# Heroku "oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I am getting below Error when Laravel 5.4 app was deployed on Heroku Platform.

```
Key path "file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable
```

This is because I have installed passport package which requires private keys and which are stored on Storage folder of Laravel App.

I can simply remove this line `/storage/*.key` from **.gitignore** fo fix the issue

But I prefer a permanent and safe solution. How can I put private keys in heroku safely.

Comment: check out this guide 
https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/267

Comment: @MoeenBasra Yes, I checked this. I am not sure how to do this `Create the keys somewhere and keep them safe and deploy them on your server so only the admins have access to those keys. Recommended solution`

Comment: This means like that make sure you or only trusted persons have access to the production server and no one else can access your server. Developer or other contributors can only access the code not the keys.

Comment: don't remove this line from .gitignore rather generate fresh keys for production server using the following command. ```php artisan passport:keys```

Comment: @MoeenBasra Yes, How to do that? Can someone link me to an Article that shows steps for these or someone who can guide me through the process.

Comment: @MoeenBasra ok I did heroku run php artisan passport:keys and I got these `Encryption keys generated successfully.` so it worked. But I still have the same error when I try to login using POSTMAN.

Comment: I added an answer for directory permissions check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like you have to do some permission change for storage directory. Use the following command for proper permissions.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

After assigning www-data proper directory and write permissions your keys must work.

Comment: so do I first upload storage folder by removing it from .gitignore file? so I have the keys uploaded and finally change the permission for storage folder

Comment: No your keys must not go with you git commit. Your local keys will not work with you production server. Keep your keys in .gitignore file commit your code and generate fresh keys on production server.

Comment: if you have already commited your code including keys then use the following command.
```git rm storage/*.key``` and commit your code again.

Comment: Hey @MoeenBasra, I cannot run `chgrp` or `chmod` and I have this issue. Is it cause I am running free Heroku? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: @ravi can you reproduce how did you do it?